# Power series of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{2n}}{2}z^{2n}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Consider the two complex power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n-(1)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{2n}}{2}z^{2n}-(2)$$.

Say the radius of convergence of **(1)** is R (finite). What can be said about the radius of convergence of **(2)**? Is it lesser? Is it greater? Can it be found using $limsup |\frac{a_{2n}}{2}|^{1/n}$ or $limsup |\frac{a_{2n}}{2}|^{1/2n}$ and why? This has really confused me hope someone could help me out thanks!

Comment: first, the denominator 2 at your second series doesn't change anything about convergence, you can drop it.

Comment: @Mher Thanks but what next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after droping that 2, denote $b_n=a_{2n}$ and $w = z^2$. Then, the radius of convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{2n}z^{2n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nw^n$$
would be
$$\frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|b_n|}} = \frac{1}{\left(\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2n]{|a_{2n}|}\right)^2} = \left(\frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}\right)^2 = R^2.$$

Therefore, it is convergent when $|z|^2 =|w| < R^2 \iff |z|<R$. So, the radius of convergence of the second series is $R$ too.

Comment: Thanks. But how is $\frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|b_n|}} = \frac{1}{\left(\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2n]{|a_{2n}|}\right)^2}$? Why is the square needed?

Comment: because $b_n=a_{2n}$ and $$\sqrt[n]{x} = \left(\sqrt[2n]{x}\right)^2$$